# An application of the dominated convergence theorem to a convolution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f, g$ be bounded measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume that $g$ is integrable and $\int g=0$. Let $g_k(x)=k^n g(kx)$. I want to show that $\psi_k(x) := (f*g_k)(x)$ satisfies $\lim_{k\to\infty}\psi_k(x)=0$ for almost every $x$.

---

I compute that
$$\psi_k(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f\left(x-\frac{y}{k}\right)g(y)dy.$$
The integrand is dominated in modulus by $\lVert f\rVert_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}g(y)$, which is integrable and $f\left(x-\frac{y}{k}\right)g(y)\to f(x)g(y)$ pointwise. Thus, we can apply the dominated convergence theorem for each $x$ to conclude that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \psi_k(x) =\int f(x)g(y)dy=0.$$
Is this correct? I seem to obtain the result is valid for all $x$ and just almost every $x$. What is going on?

Comment: Where does the convergence $f(x-\frac{y}{k})\rightarrow f(x)$ come from, when $f$ is only supposed to be measurable?

Comment: I see. Do I have to use here that if $f$ is measurable, then it is only almost everywhere continuous in general?

Comment: Measurability simply isn't enough to conclude the convergence. I don't see how to proof the statement without assuming some continuity (usually on $g$). And another minor detail, the integrand in your formula for $\psi_k(x)$ is in modulus bounded by $\Vert f \Vert_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)}\vert g(y)\vert$ a.e., the absolute value around $g$ is missing.

Comment: I think you could use Lusin’s Theorem and absolute continuity of the integral to show that the absolute value of the limit is less than $\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0$. The result then would of course follow.